# Set partition with fixed size

Tags: python-3.x

I need to find the set partition with fixed size blocks. For example set S=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) and I want to partition it as block of (4,2,1). The answers are

```
([1,2,3,4][5,6][7])
([2,3,4,5][6,7][1])
 ([1,4,5,6][2,3][7])
 .....................
 .....................
```

Anybody knows how to solve it in Python easily. Please give some clue

Comment: So you want a list with three elements, each element is a set and the size of those sets are 4, 2 and 1. And as sets are unordered, (1,2,3,4) and (4,1,3,2) would be the same. Did I get your requirements right?

Comment: Yes (1,2,3,4) and (4,1,2,3) is treated as same set. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following function:

```
from itertools import permutations

def take(l, partition):
  if len(partition) == 1:
    for p in permutations(l):
      yield (p,)
  else:
    for p in permutations(l,partition[0]):
      for t in take([x for x in l if x not in p], partition[1:]):
        yield (p,) + t
```

Then `take([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],(4,2,1))` should be what you are looking for.

EDIT: Different solution now I understand the requirements better:

```
from itertools import permutations

def take(l, partition):
  offsets = [0]
  for x in partition:
    offsets.append(offsets[-1]+x)
  for p in permutations(l):
    yield frozenset([frozenset(p[offsets[i]:offsets[i+1]]) for i in range(len(offsets)-1)])


for x in frozenset(take([1,2,3,4,5],(3,1,1))):
  print([[z for z in y] for y in x])
```

Comment: OR you could just use `[(p[0:4],p[4:6],p[6:8]) for p in permutations(a)]`. I guess I was overcomplicating things in my answer...

Comment: Please tell me how to delete duplicate  if i take input take([1,2,3],(2,1))it results as follows((1, 2), (3,))
((1, 3), (2,))
((2, 1), (3,))
((2, 3), (1,))
((3, 1), (2,))
((3, 2), (1,))

Comment: You have to replace `permutations` by `combinations`.

Comment: Friend I have already changed that permutations into combinations. But , it still not working . If i call take([1,2,3,4,5],(3,1,1)) it gives output as ((1, 2, 3), (4,), (5,))
((1, 2, 3), (5,), (4,))
((1, 2, 4), (3,), (5,))
((1, 2, 4), (5,), (3,))
((1, 2, 5), (3,), (4,))
((1, 2, 5), (4,), (3,))
((1, 3, 4), (2,), (5,))
((1, 3, 4), (5,), (2,))  Any way to filter duplicates from these

Comment: If you consider every permutation a duplicate, you probably want the logic of a `set`. I added another version that should fit these requirements.

Comment: Dear friend that exactly I was looking for. You made my day easy. many many thanks. May I get your details so that I can acknowledge you in my work.

Comment: No need to acknowledge anything. Just mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109897/discussion-between-stephan-w-and-narayan-changder).

Comment: This is a highly inefficient method, as going through permutations makes no sense here.  Not even worth considering past toy examples.

Answer (score 3):

You have to permute your table in 7*6*5*4*3*2*1 ways and then each table cut into parts.

For example:

```
def permute(table):
    return [[],[],[],[],...]//table of permuted tables


def cut_into_parts(lengths_list, table):
    rlist = []
    for i in lengths_list[:-1]:
        rlist.append(table[:-len(table) + i])
        table = table[i:]
    rlist.append(table[:lengths_list[-1]])
    return rlist
```

I hope it is a helpful and easy way to do this.

Comment: Thank you  let me try this way.

Comment: list parameter in second function is list of lengths of tables after cutting

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented simply by combining partitioning techniques with `itertools.combinations` as:

```
def partition_groups(collection, groups):
  if len(groups) == 1: yield [collection]; return
  import itertools
  for selection in itertools.combinations(range(len(collection)), groups[0]):
    yield from [[[collection[i] for i in selection]] + x for x in partition_groups([collection[i] for i in range(len(collection)) if not i in selection], groups[1:])]
```