# How many unique combinations can I make with 18 elements (2a, 2b, 2c, 3d, 4e, 5f) that I distribute into 6 groups of 3?

Tags: math, excel-formula, combinatorics

I have 18 elements `(2a, 2b, 2c, 3d, 4e, 5f)` that I need to distribute into 6 groups of 3.
I want to now the number of unique combinations I can make with those rules.

I read various website but as of now I only find way to measure the combination of 18 *different* elements into 6 group of 3

```
=(FACT(18)/FACT(18-3))*(FACT(15)/FACT(15-3))*(FACT(12)/FACT(12-3))*(FACT(9)/FACT(9-3))*(FACT(6)/FACT(6-3))
```

And I’m not even sure of what I did :D

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question. Why are you asking on Stack Overflow rather than e.g. on [mathematics.se]?

Comment: because I didn’t know this website ;) thanks a lot

Comment: [Now you've asked the question on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4322825/how-many-unique-combinations-can-i-make-with-18-elements-2a-2b-2c-3d-4e-5f), and you're unsatisfied by the answer because it's formulated in math terms rather than on excel terms. Sorry for the frustration. If you edit your question here to make it more like an excel problem, perhaps it can be reopened.

Comment: This does sound like a problem that would be suitable for dynamic programming.

Comment: Here is a horribly-bad bruteforce solution in python with `sympy.utilities.iterables.multiset_partitions`. It works when counting the number of ways to distribute 9 elements into 3 groups of 3, but it's too slow for your problem of 6 groups of 3. `sum(1 for p in multiset_partitions('aabbccdddeeeefffff', 6) if all(len(x) == 3 for x in p))`.

Comment: Another way to formulate the problem is this: You want to count the number of matrices with 6 rows of 6 columns of nonnegative integer coefficients, such that each row sums to 3 (each row corresponds to one group) and the columns sum to 2,2,2,3,4,5 respectively (each column corresponds to one letter).

Comment: [This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36768611/3080723) is also too inefficient with the 18 items.